# Does matchit pakage makes different result every time?

Tags: r

Each time I use a matchit package, the results of conditional logistic regression are different.

Is it right?

```
df.final = as.data.frame(na.omit(df))
opt.psm.out4 = matchit(treat~ gr_age+sex+dx_htn+dx_dm+dx_ckd+gr_cci, method = "nearest", data = df.final, ratio=3)
opt.data4 = match.data(opt.psm.out4)

match.matrix<-opt.psm.out4[["match.matrix"]] 
#Getting strata from nearest neighbor matching 
opt.data4$subclass <- vapply(rownames(opt.data4), function(x) {   
  out <- which(rownames(match.matrix) == x | apply(match.matrix, 1, function(y) x %in% y))
  if (length(out) == 0) out <- NA_integer_   
  out 
}, integer(1L))  
cbind(table(opt.data4$subclass ))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an element of randomness when using `matchit()` and ties are present in the data. A tie occurs when two units of the same treatment group have the same propensity score. In versions of `MatchIt` prior to 4.0.0, a member of the tie is randomly sampled, so you may get different results each time.

In `MatchIt` 4.0.0, which is now on CRAN, you should get the same results each time unless you reshuffle the dataset or select a random matching order. Ties are resolved by choosing units based on the order of the data. This adds a level of arbitrariness but ensures results are replicable when using the exact same dataset.